# I can't install OSX Lion from DVD, because I receive an error

Tags: macos, dvd

I tried to install OSX Lion from DVD, but when I boot from the dvd I receive bootstrapper crashed error. How can I fix that? Maybe the disc is scratched, or what's the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Apple never issued Lion on DVD. Where did you get this DVD from?

Comment: I burnt the original image. If you can tell me a method how to install a clean version of system let me know pls.

Comment: Apple has also never to my knowledge directly provided the image, though it is possible to extract it from the Mac App Store download or via Internet Recovery.  Where did you get the image from?

Comment: I extracted it from the installer. http://lifehacker.com/5823096/how-to-burn-your-own-lion-install-dvd-or-flash-drive

So do you know guys what's the problem and/or how can I install a clean version of osx?

Comment: Try burning another

Answer (score 1):

You can do a clean installation from the [recovery partition](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4718):

- Restart or start up and hold ⌘R after the screen turns on
- Erase the drive from Disk Utility (without it the next step would only do an upgrade install)
- Choose Reinstall Mac OS X